# In Python, how would I group specific items into a list of lists according to the end of a string?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings, as follows:

```
[https://test.com/id/51?nid=36202, https://test.com/id/513?nid=36202, 
https://test.com/id/531?nid=39542, https://test.com/id/5645?nid=28502,  
https://test.com/id/1233?nid=43812, https://test.com/id/7844?nid=43812,
https://test.com/id/54432?nid=44372,https://test.com/id/22185?nid=44372,
https://test.com/id/11063985?nid=44372, https://test.com/id/6110343?nid=8532, https://test.com/id/33218875?nid=26032]
```

For strings that end with the same NID, I want to group those together into one list of themselves within this larger list. So, eventually, it would be:

```
[[https://test.com/id/51?nid=36202, https://test.com/id/513?nid=36202], 
[https://test.com/id/531?nid=39542], [https://test.com/id/5645?nid=28502],
[https://test.com/id/1233?nid=43812, https://test.com/id/7844?nid=43812],
[https://test.com/id/54432?nid=44372,https://test.com/id/22185?nid=44372,
https://test.com/id/11063985?nid=44372], [https://test.com/id/6110343?nid=8532], 
[https://test.com/id/33218875?nid=26032]]
```

I've managed to get the top list sorted by using the built in sorted() feature in Python, but I cannot figure out how to group it the way I need it to be grouped. The NID can also be varying length, so I don't believe I can use a regular expression, but I'm also quite new to this and would appreciate any sort of help or suggestions anyone might be willing to offer.

Thank you!

Comment: use `itertools.groupby` with possibly the same predicate you used on `sorted`

Comment: Why not a dicionary with the "nid" as key?

Comment: Refer the dupe and do something like `[list(i) for _,i in groupby(l, key=lambda x:x.rsplit('=')[-1])]`